# database update all table with different values

Tags: android

I want to update all rows in the table by inputting different values. Help me please. My code

```
 public boolean updateData(String id,String name, String number_phone, String about, Integer price, String color){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_1, id);
    contentValues.put(COL_2, name);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, number_phone);
    contentValues.put(COL_4, about);
    contentValues.put(COL_5, price);
    contentValues.put(COL_6, color);

    db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "ID = " + id, null);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your db.update statement to

```
db.update(TABLE_NAME, //table
            contentValues, // column/value
           "ID  = ?", // selections
            id);
```

Comment: I can't just write id, the program tells me the error, but when i write new String[]{id} the program doesn't tell me error, but that does not solve my problem